# How to run the "runas" command without writing the password

Tags: batch-file, active-directory, runas

I need to run the "runas" command for log on automatically an Application User, on an Active Directory. Then I need run an executable file.

Can I do this in some way or work around to do not type the password?

Comment: Is this batch file running at startup or logon?  A bit more info may help get an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Summary

Runas might not be supported but you could use a **freeware** utility CPAU  http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/cpau/index.htm

This utility will allow you to launch an application using a different set of credentials then the current user. The neat advantage with CPAU over runas is that you can specify both the username and password at runtime. With the runas command you'd first have to configure a cached credential or be prompted for password at each run.

## Examples

Using CPAU to launch iexplore.exe you could use a statement like:

from cmd prompt:

```
cd <path to cpau> -d
cpau.exe  /u domain\username  /p 123456  /ex "c:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" /lwp
```

from powershell script:

```
cd <path to cpau> -d
invoke-expression "cpau.exe  /u 'domain\username'  /p '123456'  /ex 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe' /lwp"
```

`/lwp` means to Load With Profile, and can be replaced with `/lwop` Load Without Profile

Comment: I do this: _Open cmd as Administrator_. Then I use command **cpau -u domain\username -p xxx -ex "C:\windows\explorer.exe
"** but I get error ***Windows cannot access the specificed device, path, or file. Yoy may not have the appropiate permissions to access the item.***

And its appears another dialog with title ***shell:::{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}*** and the same error message.

Comment: It's probably because you didn't install the utility properly.

Answer (score 2):

Use option /savecred, then the password will be saved when you have typed it and not asked for again. (You can can use "runas /?" to get help for this command.)

Answer (score 1):

what about [RUNASSPC](http://www.robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html)?
You create an certificate for needed program, the password et. is saved as encrypted file so for example guest user can run only the particular software as administrator.
[image: RUNASSPC window]

and the license:

> RunasSpc is free for private use.
>   For companies we deliver a licensed version of runasspc, registered to the enterprise`s name..

Comment: For domains it need registration

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this.  In my case I was launching a scheduled task at login.  Below is the command I used to launch the elevated powershell window without a password prompt:

```
powershell.exe "Start-Process powershell -verb runAs"
```

I had it set to run with highest privileges.