# Run program automatically as a specific user

Tags: script, runas, parameters

So I know, that I could just create a shortcut with `RunAs` but I was wondering, whether it would be possible to pass the password already as a parameter to the script, so I do not have to type it in all the time.

Any advise?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/581548/runas-savecred-ask-for-password-if-another-user-runs-the-same-batch-file#903881) works for you?

Comment: @berserck Not quite what im searching for, I'm currently trying out cpau and runasspc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than putting the password in the batch file you can use the `/savecred` switch to get it to save your password for you after you enter it.

It will mean that you can always run **any** program as that user in future, but it is slightly more secure than leaving your password in plaintext in a batch file.

---

`runas` cannot be supplied a password, it was [specifically written to forbid accepting a password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16116329/278545) on the command line for security reasons.

An alternative program might be [cpau](https://superuser.com/a/590640/19943) which will accept a password.

Comment: That's a good idea, but not exactly what I need. It should save the credentials only for this specific program...

Comment: Apparently they decided that runas should never do that for the exact reason I've stated. I've linked to another answer that provides an alternative.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help! I'm using now cpau, as you mentioned above, it works now perfectly.